# How to retrieve dynamic box values (true or false if checked or not) - Angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I use Angular 6, I get data from a JSON file and I display it in a table. I would like to be able to check the checkboxes in order to be able to carry out POST processing later for checkbox checked (so true).
The problem is that I get dynamic values so I have to be able to retrieve the value of a checkbox (true or false) even if the JSON file changes (adding data).
I can not get the value of checkbox (true or false) dynamically...
Can you help me please.

demande-ouverture-compte.component.html :

```html
<h2>Demandes d'ouverture de compte</h2>
<hr>
<form #form = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "getVerificationCheckboxValidation(form)" [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nom</th>
        <th scope="col">N° demande</th>
        <th scope="col">date</th>
        <th scope="col">Validation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let demande of demandes; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ demande.nom }}</th>
        <td>{{ demande.id_demande }}</td>
        <td>{{ demande.date }}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="test" id="customCheck{{ i }}" [checked]="demande.checked">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{ i }}">Valider la demande d'ouverture</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let demande of demandes; let j = index">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="demande.checked" formControlName="hello" id="{{demande.roleID}}" />
       </td>
       <td>

       </td>
       <td>Voici demandes{{ j }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="col-2 offset-10 addAccount">Valider</button>
</form>

<!-- Remplacer le bouton valider par cette image -->
<!--<img src="../../assets/img/addAccount.svg" alt="" class="col-4 offset-7 addAccount">-->
```

demande-ouverture-compte.component.ts :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DemandeOuvertureCompteService } from '../demande-ouverture-compte.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demande-ouverture-de-compte',
  templateUrl: './demande-ouverture-de-compte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demande-ouverture-de-compte.component.scss']
})
export class DemandeOuvertureDeCompteComponent implements OnInit {

  demandes: Object;

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    hello: new FormControl('')
  });
  
  playerName: string;

  constructor(private demandeOuvertureCompte: DemandeOuvertureCompteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.demandeOuvertureCompte.getDemandesOuvertureCompte().subscribe(
      demandeOuvertureCompte => this.demandes = demandeOuvertureCompte 
    );
  }

  getVerificationCheckboxValidation(form: NgForm) {
 console.log(form.value.test);
 console.log(this.profileForm.value);
 console.log("test");
 console.log(this.playerName);
 return this.playerName;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for the valueChanges on FormGroup. Something like

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => console.log(value);
 )
```

Comment: It works, I get true or false by checking or unchecking a box, however I obviously receive only one object with "hello: true" or "hello: false" and those whatever the box ticked ... How can I I retrieve the id of the box in question to be able to differentiate which elements are checked?
Thanks a lot for your help ! :D

Comment: Take a look at this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374174/how-to-dynamically-define-formcontrol-name-within-ngfor-loop][1]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !