# Angular Reactive form is not taking value from hidden field?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to set product id in hidden field but when i am submitting my form hidden field value is none. If i type or change anything in that field then only field value is taken.

**TS**
[image: Typescript code]

**HTML**
[image]

**Console**
[image]

All i need is hidden field value. 
Any suggestions how to do it and any other best practice ??

Comment: as you are not applying any value in the "_id". Set the value in "_id" field, you will get the value definitely

Comment: Actually i applied - check line 7 in html , now i highlight it as well

Comment: while creating a FormGroup, check ts code line number 2. set products.id value in the ts file.

Comment: What is `products`? is it any other object in your ts?

Comment: In Ts i am storing products in eventProducts: Product[] = []; and i am iterating using *ngFor="let products of eventProducts | filter:search, let i = index"

Comment: @AjayOjha if i do like that then it will give error ERROR in src/app/event/main/event-products/event-products.component.ts(27,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'products'.

Comment: Use `patchValue` : https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value#patchvalue to update formControl value. Do it whenever your products are available in your code.

Comment: @SamarthSaxena try to fire a loop of eventProducts in the component and set the "id" value in the FormControl.

Answer (score 0):

apply the value on initialization.

```
_id: FormControl(this.products._id)
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/event/main/event-products/event-products.component.ts(27,31): error TS2339: Property 'products' does not exist on type 'EventProductsComponent'

Comment: where do u initialize the `products`

Comment: In Ts i am storing products in eventProducts: Product[] = []; and i am iterating using *ngFor="let products of eventProducts | filter:search, let i = index"

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374174/how-to-dynamically-define-formcontrol-name-within-ngfor-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use getRawValue()  method it will Retrieve all values regardless of disabled status. The value property is the best way to get the value of the group because it excludes disabled controls in the FormGroup.

```
   this.productForm.patchValue({
      _id: products._id }   
    );

   productForm.getRawValue()
```

Comment: Not working as well. It is giving me the same result

Comment: I have noticed. you didn't   patchValue to _id control, do that as well in TS this.productForm.patchValue({
  _id: products._id
  }
);

Comment: cause products property is not defined in ts that's why it is giving me error                 ERROR in src/app/event/main/event-products/event-products.component.ts(93,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'products'.

Comment: @SamarthSaxena okay. anyhow you can't set values to formGroup using value property you have to use patchValue or setValue method. hope you have fixed your problem

Comment: if i use patch value then all products value will be changed to that patched value.

Answer (score -1):

I know It's too late for answering the question but I had same issue in hidden fields with reactive form approach so I hope it will helpful for someone else. please use [ngModel] to set value for hidden fields. for ex -

> <input type="hidden" formControlName="type" [ngModel]="products._id">